# How to save order of relational list in Prisma?

Tags: reactjs, database, postgresql, prisma

in my Prisma schema I have a User model that contains a 1 to Many relation with a Books model that contains many scalar values. Each user can have many books, and each book can only have one user.

When I fetch the user, I get an array of Books object from the data fetched. The order of this array is from the time that the Book is created. In my app, I want the user to be able to change the order of their Books. How am I able to change the order of the Books displayed and have it saved for subsequent fetches. How can I achieve it when the Books just relational keys in the User?

Answer (score 0):

One possible technique is to add a column to `books`, call it `display_seq`. This column would be null-able and without default value. The user can the specify the desired sequences specifying specifying only those with a desired sequence. You then sort by `display_seq` and the current created date. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=669f41f8ab98e626f2c8434aeddcfd6c), has other examples also)

```
select * 
  from books 
 order by usr_id, display_seq, create_dt;
```